# Why are my .resx files producing an empty output?

Tags: asp.net, resources

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC 3.0 application. Then, when I create a `Foo.resx`, it successfully generates the expected `.cs` output. But when I create something like `Foo.en.resx` it just outputs an empty `.cs` file. Even when I actively press the `Run Custom Tool` context menu.

Any tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into issues with this too. It seems (I read this somewhere on MSDN but can't find the link) that code is only needed for the Invariant resx (Foo.resx). In fact, in my experience, having a .cs file for every localized .resx actually breaks the application.

**Edit** is this of help? [Resource (RESX) files messed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343813/resource-resx-files-messed-up)

Comment: And that makes sense indeed :)